# Converting a large base 62 value to base 16 with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, radix

I need to covert a base 62 value like 4u8LPK581OHn7kRqRqP9ks to base 16 using JavaScript. Using a [php based tool](http://convertxy.com/index.php/numberbases/), I can see the result should be A12D08BC6D93BC4E8EA847434C960416.

Looking at some npm nodules like [base62](https://www.npmjs.org/package/base62), I thought I could take the value to base 10 then convert to base 16 via toString like this Base62.decode('4u8LPK581OHn7kRqRqP9ks').toString(16).

However, because the base 62 value is large, JavaScript wants to represent it using scientific notation which munges the conversion to base 10 and finally base 16.

I tried using [javascript-biginteger](https://github.com/silentmatt/javascript-biginteger) to parse the base 62 value. But [parse()](https://github.com/silentmatt/javascript-biginteger/blob/master/biginteger.js#L289) restricts the radix to 2 - 32.

Does anyone have suggestions for an alternate approach?

Comment: Have you tried this:
https://www.npmjs.org/package/bases

Comment: Yes, but I run into the same problem. After 12 characters JS switches to scientific notation and throws off the result.

Answer (score 0):

use bigint and decode it yourself I think that single for loop is not that hard to code

not a JAVA coder so I stick to C++/pseudocode:

```
//base62Alphabet[] = {a,b,c,...,A,B,C,...,0,1,2,...};
bigint out;
char in[]="4u8LPK581OHn7kRqRqP9ks\0";
int i,d;
for (out=0,i=0;in[i];i++)
 {
 out*=62;
 d=unsigned int(in[i]);
 // here convert d from char to value from alphabet
 // for example i found this base62Alphabet in that case
 // (more common is that numbers are first instead of last)
      if (d<unsigned int('A')) d+= 0-'a';
 else if (d<unsigned int('0')) d+=26-'A';
 else                            d+=52-'0';
 out+=d;
 }
// here out should hold your value
// so just print it in hex (bigint libs should have some function for that)
// or code it yourself it is similar code but instead *=62 you div/mod by 16
```

[notes]

- this should work for MSB first notation (most significant digits are first on the left)
- also check what alphabet your numbers are using and change the code accordingly
- the unsigned int conversion from char is necessary on some platforms
- because char is signed so the decoding conditions could get wrong without it...
- the [alphabet is from here](http://www.kerstner.at/en/2012/07/shortening-strings-using-base-62-encoding/)

Answer (score 0):

I have a library I wrote for generic radix conversions in JS that might be helpful to you.
https://github.com/cflynn07/power-radix

Quick example in node REPL

```
> var PowerRadix = require('./lib/index');
undefined
> var base16 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
undefined
> new PowerRadix('4u8LPK581OHn7kRqRqP9ks', 62).toArray(base16)
[ 'A',
  1,
  2,
  'D',
  0,
  8,
  'B',
  'C',
  6,
  'D',
  9,
  3,
  'B',
  'C',
  4,
  'E',
  8,
  'E',
  'A',
  8,
  4,
  7,
  4,
  3,
  4,
  'C',
  9,
  6,
  0,
  4,
  1,
  6 ]
> new PowerRadix('4u8LPK581OHn7kRqRqP9ks', 62).toString(base16)
'A12D08BC6D93BC4E8EA847434C960416'
```

I need to add additional documentation + tests to show this, but you can also pass an array of any values as the second argument to the constructor to be the source radix. For ex:

```
var base16 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
> new PowerRadix('4u8LPK581OHn7kRqRqP9ks', '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('')).toString(base16);
'A12D08BC6D93BC4E8EA847434C960416'
```

**EDIT**:
Added example test:
https://github.com/cflynn07/power-radix/blob/v2.3.0/test/index.spec.js#L197